# What do you call a URL to a folder, and not a specific file?

Tags: url, path, directory, terminology

What do you call a URL that doesn't reference a specific file?

For example:

**http://www.example.com/images**

**http://www.example.com/articles/puppytraining**

as opposed to

**http://www.example.com/images/avatar.jpg**

**http://www.example.com/articles/puppytraining/index.php**

I was thinking "Directory URL" or "Folder URL" but wanted to know if there was a naming convention.

Comment: You mean URL rewriting?

Comment: @C0dekid no, just literally what is the name for a URL that points to a folder on the internet

Comment: i'm really confused by your question, I have no idea though. Maybe something with directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, an URL pointing to a folder is still called URL.
URL stands for Uniform Resource Locator and I believe a folder can be a resource.